# How to format a time-stamp to show the date only in a grid view

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In an aspx page I am binding the labels like this:

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date of Joining">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("date_of_joining") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Paid Priviledge Date">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("paid_priviledge_date") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

And in the code behind I'm binding the grid view like this :(minimum code is given)

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt2;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

But the gridview columns show the date like this :

```
4/12/2011 12:00:00 AM    
4/4/2011 12:00:00 AM
```

Please suggest how to remove the time stamp part and to display only the date part.

I know how to do this by formatting using ToString and SubString. But I am not able to do this in gridview.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a `FormatDate` method in your codebehind, and call that from your gridview.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx
http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

This part will go in your code behind

```
private object FormatDate(DateTime input)
{
    return String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", input);
}
```

And this bit will go in your markup

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date of Joining">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# FormatDate(Eval("date_of_joining")) %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Paid Priviledge Date">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# FormatDate(Eval("paid_priviledge_date")) %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is what I would call a [D.R.Y.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) approach to the problem. If you ever need to modify the formatting in any way. You can simply edit the code behind method and it will rain down sweet love to all of your markup.

Comment: I am sorry Sir ..after so many days when I looked back to this solution I found that I have ticked ilivewithian's answer as the most suitable one ..but actually your answer is the most efficient one.I am ticking your's as the correct one now.Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: If you do it in the markup you can make the change with out having to recompile.

Comment: @Chad, a down-vote because it's not your preference is a little odd to me. There are a number of ways to skin a cat, mine happens to be one of those ways. I prefer to NOT do it in the markup because I like to keep it clean. If you don't want to recompile, set your format string in the App.config.

Answer (score 25):

You can specify format strings for the eval statement:

```
Eval("date_of_joining", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
```

Comment: Great i was looking exactly for this sort of super useful answer.Thanks a lot sir

Comment: I don't want to sound like "I'm right and you're wrong", as this is absolutely a right answer. My question however is... what happens when you need to change the formatting of the date? Do you go through all your markup to find all instances? By setting it as a code behind function, you can change it in one spot and it will propagate down to all instances. [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: Fair point, I'm guilty of typing the first thing that works into a stackoverflow answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use `"{0:d}"` for short date format.
Try

```
 Text='<%# Eval("paid_priviledge_date","{0:d}") %>'
```

and

```
Text='<%# Eval("date_of_joining", "{0:d}") %>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) in a bound field the same can be set as below:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("paid_priviledge_date","{0:d}") %>'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Text='<%# (Convert.ToDateTime((Eval("date_of_joining")))).ToShortDateString() %>'
```

This is the simplest way I discovered.