# #eval phone number in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string, gridview

I want  to display the phone number as mask format (999)999-9999 in asp.net gridview.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("OrgContactPhone").ToString().Length>50)?Eval("OrgContactPhone").ToString().Substring(0,50):Eval("OrgContactPhone") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

So two questions.

1. How to format it? I know that there is string.format something. But please see next question.
2. If it is null, display nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [link to a similar (previous) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807004/how-to-format-a-time-stamp-to-show-the-date-only-in-a-grid-view/5807076#5807076) that I wrote.

Ultimately you want to have a code behind function to return your formatted text. This function will allow you to have uniform formatting across all of your phone numbers. And if you ever need to change the formatting, you just need to change a single method.

```
public object FormatPhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
{
   // return nothing if the string is null
   if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNumber))
   {
       return "";    
   }

   // invalid phone number submitted
   if(phoneNumber.Length != 10)
   {
       throw new System.ArgumentException("Phone Number must contain 10 digits", "phoneNumber");
   }

   // probably want one more check to ensure the string contains numbers and not characters, but then again, hopefully that's handled on input validation.

   // if the int is valid, return the formatted text
   return string.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}",
          phoneNumber.Substring(0, 3),
          phoneNumber.Substring(3, 3),
          phoneNumber.Substring(6));
}
```

And you call it from your aspx page like this.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# FormatPhoneNumber(Eval("OrgContactPhone").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Did you mean for phoneNumber to be a string (or to call `ToString` on it?  int doesn't have a `Substring` method.

Comment: pass int phoneNumber or string phoneNumber?

Comment: It's questions like these that show me how much I rely on my VS IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you check if the phone number length is greather than 50? 
This would do the job I think. But I don't like to do int.Parse for every line...

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# 
(Eval("OrgContactPhone") != null ? (((Eval("OrgContactPhone").ToString().Length>50) ? int.Parse(Eval("OrgContactPhone").Substring(0,10)).ToString("(###)###-####") : "") : (int.Parse(Eval("OrgContactPhone")).ToString("(###)###-####")) : ""%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```